# Scanf to array in for ignored my first input

Tags: c, scanf

```
int Q, A[Q], B[Q];
scanf("%d", &Q);

for(int i=0; i<Q; i++){
    scanf("%d %d", &A[i], &B[i]);
}

for(int i=0; i<Q; i++){
    printf("%d %d\n", A[i], B[i]); //check val
}
```

if I type
3
1 2
3 4
5 6

the output will be
2 2
4 4
6 6

why? pls help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages.  While you've made a good attempt at including minimal code, you've probably gone a little too far.  We really need to see how the variables, especially `A` and `B`, are defined.  Please read about how to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/))
 — the same idea by a different name.

Comment: In line `printf("%d %d\n", A[i], B[i]); ` it prints the same value twice. It seems A and B are the same. Find out why.

Comment: I edited my code to show how I declared A and B, but I don't know why A and B prints the same value

Comment: `int Q, A[Q], B[Q];` not good as `Q` has no value assigned yet. Move `int A[Q], B[Q];` til **after** you have scanned a value for `Q`. See https://ideone.com/ubLn24

Comment: BTW: **Always** check the return value from `scanf`. Like: `if (scanf("%d", &Q) != 1) exit(1);`

Comment: BTW: Since you are using VLAs (i.e. `int A[Q], B[Q];`) you should check `Q` for a MAX allowed value **before** creating the VLAs. Like `if (scanf("%d", &Q) != 1) exit(1); if (Q > MAX_ALLOWED_Q || Q <= 0) {puts("Illegal Q"); exit(1);}`. I you don't then the user input may result in stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

just write

```
    int Q;
    scanf("%d", &Q);
    int A[Q], B[Q];
```

instead of :

```
int Q, A[Q], B[Q];
scanf("%d", &Q);
```

it's a matter of the order of declaration as in your code, you are declaring  `A` and `B` of unknown size as `Q` wasn't initialized yet so your code will produce undefined behavior, also begging from C99 standard, you can declare arrays that are created in the stack with size equal to a variable that have a value where that value will be used to initiate the size of the array.

Comment: Not exactly. C99 defines Variable Length Arrays, but they are an **optional** feature since C11. You can safely use them with clang or gcc, but at least Microsoft compilers do not support it and correctly define `__STDC_NO_VLA__` to advertise that they do not. Said differently, if portability is important, it is better to avoid them...